# Count number of lines without header in a file using CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, count, text-files

I need to count the number of lines after the header in a text file from the Windows command prompt. In my research thus far I found this statement:

```
Type d:\test\test_viewpayment4.txt | Find /V /C "~~~" >> d:\test\Result.txt
```

It works. However, the number of data lines is 100, and the output is 101, which includes the header.

By the way, I just found a comment that advises to use `more+2`. I put this in as follows:

```
Type d:\test\test_viewpayment4.txt | Find more+2 /V /C "~~~" >> d:\test\Result.txt
```

It doesn't work. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pipe output of more into the the find command.
Use

```
Type d:\test\test_viewpayment4.txt | more +2 | find /V /C "~~~" >> d:\test\Result.txt
```